# How to override and interface and call "base" interface in ASP.NET Core built-in DI container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

Suppose I have an interface registered by 3pty library to the default container

```
// 3pty lib
public interface IFoo {
  SayHello();
  SayBye();
}

internal sealed class FooInternal : IFoo { ... }

public static WithFoo(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection) { 
  serviceCollection.AddScoped<IFoo, FooInternal>();
}
```

And I do want to overwrite the `SayBye()` method. I've created a class

```
class FooProxy : IFoo {
   private readonly IFoo baseFoo;
   public FooProxy(IFoo baseFoo) {
     this.baseFoo = baseFoo;
   }

   public void SayHello() { baseFoo.SayHello(); }
   public void SayBye() { ... }
}
```

Now the problem I'm facing is how to hook it up to dependency injection.
I've tried:

```
// leads to infinite recursion death
services.AddScoped<IFoo>((sp) => new FooProxy(sp.GetRequiredService<IFoo>()));
```

And also:

```
public class FooProxy : IFoo {
  private readonly Func<IFoo> baseFoo;
  SayHello() { baseFoo().SayHello(); }
}

// leads to object disposed error 
services.AddScoped<IFoo>((sp) => new FooProxy(() => sp.GetRequiredService<IFoo>()));
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? the way you have implemented FooProxy it's infinite recursion  actually

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - its not ? I do have a 3pty library that puts the interface to container / in my code I do want to in some cases make a call to that interface.

Comment: Your `FooProxy` is a Decorator, which is something that is hard to achieve with MS.DI out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something you can achieve using Decorator Pattern.

For this there is one library.

- https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor

  ```
  service.AddScoped<IFoo,FooConcrete>(); // This I believe register by Third Party

  service.Decorate<IFoo,FooProxy>(); // This is you will add.
  ```
- Another way which is bit not good.

  ```
  public interface IFooProxy: IFoo
  {

  }

  public class FooProxy : IFooProxy
  {
          public FooProxy(IFoo foo)
        {
        }
  }

    // Configure Sevices
    services.AddScoped<IFooProxy,FooProxy>();
  ```